# What should happen when running tsc with no command line options?

Tags: typescript

Newbie here. I'm new to TypeScript am trying to convert a small JS app to TS. I've been working with ChatGPT, and it's telling me that running `tsc` with no command line options should result in the generation of `.js` files in the same directories as their associated .ts file, as long as the `.ts` file are in directories which are in the `"include"` block in `tsconfig.json`.

When I run `tsc` (no command line options) at first I got a few errors (so it seemed to be finding my files), which I resolved and now tsc gives no terminal output and I see no `.js` files generated.

Should I see `.js` files? I'm not sure if ChatGPT is BS'ing me on the expected behavior.

I tried running `tsc <filename>` to transpile them individually but get piles of errors which ChatGPT says is because there are interdependencies and all of the files need to be transpiled at the same time. Again, I'm not sure if it's BS'ing me on this or not, so trying to get a sense of how things "should" work.

I also tried `tsc --watch` and it seems to detect when I make changes to my `.ts` files but I never see it generate any `.js` files. Not in the directories the `.ts` files are in or anywhere else in my project folder as far as I can see.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["node"],
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "backend",
    "frontend"
  ]
}
```

My files are `./backend/backend.ts` `./frontend/index.ts` `./frontend/app.ts`

Thanks much for any insights anyone may have!

Comment: you have `noEmit: true` so `tsc` is just type-checking (files specified in `include`). TypeScript offers documentation for all config parameters, see [noEmit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit) and [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include).

Comment: Learn TS by a smaller demo. And providing a minimal reproduction here may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This works form me - tsconfig.json. If you want to see builded files, you cannot use "noEmit": true, remove it and add "outDir": "build". Somethimes there is a problem with moduleResolution and target (js version), try es5. And try to remove  "module": "esnext", it could help as well.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```